# "My account" page mockup - change password form on this page?

Tags: password, mockup

I am mocking up a very minimalistic user-account page. It consists of just three functions - a counter that displays your available uses, field to redeem a code and a link to a form where you can change the password.

[image: My_account mockup]

What do you think: Maybe I should include the password form right on this page, instead of having it available after clicking the link?

And I don't know about counter free queries. I don't like it, but can't seem to come up with a better way to display it, can you maybe point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you decided to have it on a different page? Is there another way to get to it other than the link on the account page? Can you explain what you mean by "counter free queries"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Overall this looks like a great start.** However, consider the following points to help streamline the UX making your design more efficient and easier to use.

**If possible make one purpose per page.** *You don't want a password form validation error scenario on the Promo Code page.* One purpose pages are also favorable for keyboard/enter form submissions. Minimizing mouse-keyboard switching is efficient.

**Why not just put 'Change Password' under the 'My Account' page?** 
If you are going to allow the user to change their password, for security purposes, confirm that they are the account owner. *Forgot Password* and *Change Password* are two different cases with slightly different requirements.

GitHub is a good example:

[GitHub http://gyroscopestudios.com/stackexchange/git-screen.gif](http://gyroscopestudios.com/stackexchange/git-screen.gif)

**Consider each element on the screen carefully.** 
As a general rule, anything that can be removed, should be removed. It serves to distract the user, which can lead to confusion and frustration.

Your sketch appears to be a page that the user has already entered their credentials. 'Change password' does not have relevant context here. And reconsider the out-bound links ("Theme by...") as a siphon taking the user away from the task at hand.

**If there are really only three things going on, that's all that should be there.** Think about the user's experience. Do they really care whose theme it is, or is it more important that they use their promo codes?

Answer (score 1):

What does the "Change password" link actually do?

If it shows a modal pop-up over this page, then I think a link is ok.

A link could also be good to display the form inline when requested - that way the page isn't cluttered until the user needs the form, and maintains the same context.

If it actually takes you to another page, it seems a bit odd. Why would another page be necessary? If it's part of the "profile" then it should probably live here w/other profile info.

As for the queries, maybe a graphical depiction? What do users want/expect to see?

- Total used to date vs. how many remaining
- A graph of queries used over time w/# remaining
- Different tiers of queries available for comparison to what the user has?

The promo code to add queries seems far more prominent that the # available.
Would suggest trying alternate layouts where the query counter is more prominent (if you haven't already) to determine which info people actually want to see.

Answer (score 1):

Having the 'forgot password' on another 'view' is not necessarily bad if you're able to influence how the developer implements the page transitions. Consider using one of these very smooth [page transitions examples](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) like a flip, slide in etc which allows the user to quickly view the 'hidden' forgot password view or navigate back to the normal landing view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with putting the "change password" functionality on the page is that you risk confusing the user.  Consider the following (slightly modified) screenshot of an actual forum's "edit profile" page:

[image]

Is a user who wants to add an ICQ number to their profile required to change their password while doing so?